# Help finding the inverse of an exponential function

Tags: exponential-function, problem-solving

$$f(x)=6^{3x+9}-2.$$

I got to one step, but I became lost. I understand that I'm converting it into logarithmic form, but I don't understand what the next steps are.

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=6^{3x+9}-2 \\
x&=6^{3y+9} -2 \\
x+2&=6^{3y+9} \ldots
\end{align*}

Comment: When I clicked on the link, which many will not-you should go to the trouble of typing the problem here, I need permission to view it.  -1.  If you are asking for help from volunteers, make it easy for them to help.

Comment: Sorry about that! Will do

Comment: [Here is a useful link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick tutorial on how to type with mathematics and $\LaTeX$ on this site.

Comment: Welcome KiaJ. I applied a minimal mod to your post in the style of this site. While it may be closed, I know that you are new, don't be be disheartened. This is a busy site, and you really need to get the post right from the start, with the work that you have shown, all up front to get hits, and avoid the close votes. Again, welcome. JMoravitz's link might be the best thing you can get out of these comments. Thank's for your attentiveness.

Comment: Should I resend the question?@J. W. Perry

Comment: @KiaJ First, notice that your function is not onto in $\mathbb{R}$ and hence not invertible. You need to restrict the codomain to $[-2,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now take the base $6$ log (or the natural log) of both sides, getting $3y+9=\log_6(x+2)$ and keep working.

Comment: Thank you for helping me @RossMillikan